# Finding the MLE based on a set of derived random variables

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I've encountered a sample problem in my statistics notes which I don't understand.

Suppose $X_1,...,X_{100}$ are r.v.'s which are Poisson-distributed with parameter $\frac{\mu}{100}$. We're looking for the MLE for $\mu$. However, we can only observe $Y_1,...,Y_{100}$ which are Bernoulli distributed with value $0$ if $X_i=0$ and $1$ otherwise (this is due to technical constraints). We find that the MLE for $p=e^{{-\frac{\mu}{100}}}$ is the sample proportion $\frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=1}^{100} Y_i$. Based on this, the notes say we can derive that

$-100\log(\frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=1}^{100} Y_i)$

is the MLE for $\mu$

Does anyone have any idea how we arrive at this result? It's been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the same result of your solution, we must amend a typo in the text

> which are Bernoulli distributed with value $0$ if $X_i=0$ and 1 otherwise

It must be the converse:

**They are Bernoulli distributed with value $1$ if $X_i=0$ and $0$ otherwise**

Now it works because now your rv's become $B\Big(e^{-\frac{\mu}{100}}\Big)$

The MLE of $g(\mu)=e^{-\frac{\mu}{100}}$ is obviously

$$\widehat{g(\mu)}=\overline{Y}_{100}$$

For invariance property we can write

$$g(\hat{\mu})=\overline{Y}_{100}$$

$$e^{-\frac{\hat{\mu}}{100}}=\overline{Y}_{100}$$

now solve in $\hat{\mu}$ and get your result

---

If you use exatly the text you posted, the result is not very different...try, FYK

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, my problem is that I don't understand this invariance property you're using. Do you have complete formulation and proof?

Comment: @othi : here it is! http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~dlunn/b8_02/b8pdf_6.pdf. If there is something not clear do not hesitate to ask

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!